# How to display content in magento custom admin page?

Tags: magento

if i have to display some data from the database, how do i pass this data in the admin controller? Say i am defining a block in my controller

```
$block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/text')->setText('<h1>Main Block</h1>');
```

Can i pass any sort of data to the setText() function to display the data i require in the admin page or are there other functions? I want to display a few order no from my custom table in the back end.

I tried something like this : `$block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/text')->setText('<h1>Main Block</h1><div>'.$this->showAllRecordsAction().'</div>');`

The showAllRecordsAction() retrieves data from the custom table and displays it. When i try this out, i see the data at the top of the page and not in the content block.

How can i display it in a content block? Thanks.

Comment: I assume you write new module. Did you create admin page already? I mean did you create controller and layout update already?

Comment: Yes, i have a new module. I have the controller which gets my data from the db. I dont have a layout as i am not sure how to. I know i have to display the content through blocks, but not sure how to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to get the content displayed through a block. 
Used this code in my indexController :

```
$this->loadLayout();
$this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhelloworld/view'))
            ->renderLayout();
```

This is my View.php in the Block/View.php

```
<?php
class Foostor_Adminhelloworld_Block_View extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        $html="";
        $records = Mage::getModel('direcpay/database')->getCollection();
        foreach($records as $db_record){
        $html = $html . 'Order no : '.$db_record->getOrder_no().' Referecnce id : ';
        $html = $html . $db_record->getDirecpay_refid()."<br/>";
        }
        return $html;
```

Hope this helps someone.